# How do you map multi morpmap with same index value?

Tags: laravel

i have 2 tables ( media type and jobs )

tables

```
types (1 comic, 2 tv show, 3 movie )
jobs (1 artist, 2 actor )
```

it return nothing if i use duplicate index.

```
Relation::morphMap([
  1 => 'App\Models\Comic',
  1 => 'App\Models\Artist',
  2 => 'App\Models\Movie'
]);
```

if i change Artist index to other and set table id to 3. it works. i set in AppServiceProvider within boot function